# Cannot get sqlalchemy.orm to insert data into my postgres database table using Session.execute() during multithreading

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

First of all, I'm completely new to using databases other than sqlite, which I have only used a bit, and python is also something I've only used for about 6 months so bear with me if I miss something obvious or have completely misunderstood something.

I have a lot of historical market data I'm scraping (~15000 items for three regions) and to do it efficiently I was trying to do it by using a process for each region and then multithreading each process to get all the items. The response I get from my scraping for each item is a list of dicts which I then want to insert using `Session.execute()`. I have not gotten this to work yet (if you know a way please guide me in the right direction as well), so for now I went with only multithreading as I have successfully used that to insert data into the regionid and typeid tables.
Still I get no data inserted into my historical_data table and no errors when I run my script. I tried enabling sqlalchemy logging with

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

and that shows me what I expect for my calls to get data from the regionid and typeid tables during main, but after that nothing, does that mean I have no connection to the database after I multithread or is the logger just not good at handling multithreading?

With the regionid and typeid tables, I used Session.merge() and handled the data for each item with a for-loop so I'm guessing it's my use of `Session.execute()` that's off?

I try to insert all my historical data into a postgres database using sqlalchemy.orm
The actual script I use to try to insert the data is as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Start database session")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    ini_params()
    print("Get typeids and regionids from database")
    typeids = get_typeids() #get all typeids from typeid table
    regionids = get_regionids() #get all regionids from regionid table
    typeids = typeid_test_list #uncomment for debug
    print(typeids)
    for idx, regionid in enumerate(regionids):
        no_data = data_to_db(regionid, typeids, idx)
        #no_data = multi_processing(regionid, typeids, idx)
    print(no_data)

def data_to_db(regionid, typeids, idx):
    ini_params()
    position = int(idx)
    no_data_typeids = []
    prefix = 'Getting data for region ' + str(regionid)
    typeid_length = len(typeids)
    with tqdm(typeids, total=typeid_length, desc=prefix, position=position) as pbar:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
            futures = {executor.submit(multithread_func, typeid, regionid): typeid for typeid in typeids}
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                pbar.update(1)
    return no_data_typeids

def multithread_func(typeid, regionid):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    history = get_market_history(regionid, typeid) #URL-scraper
    if history != "error":
        import_full_history(history)
    else:
        return typeid
    return 0

def import_full_history(history):
    get_data_session = Session()
    print(type(history))
    get_data_session.execute(historical_data.insert(), item_dict)
    get_data_session.commit()
    Session.remove()
    return 0
```

and my database is built like so

**Base**

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user@localhost:5432/historic_market_data', pool_size=12, max_overflow=0)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
Base = declarative_base()
```

**regionids**

```
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
class Regionid(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'regionids'
    regionid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    query = Session.query_property()
    def __init__(self, regionid):
        self.regionid = regionid
```

**typeids**

```
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
class Typeid(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'typeids'
    typeid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    query = Session.query_property()
    def __init__(self, typeid):
        self.typeid = typeid
```

**historical_data**

```
class Historical_data(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'historical_data'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    typeid = Column('typeid', Integer, ForeignKey('typeids.typeid'))
    regionid = Column('regionid', Integer, ForeignKey('regionids.regionid'))
    date = Column(Date)
    average = Column(Float)
    highest = Column(Float)
    lowest = Column(Float)
    order_count = Column(Integer)
    volume = Column(Integer)
    buy_weighted_avg = Column(Float)
    buy_maxval = Column(Float)
    buy_minval = Column(Float)
    buy_stddev = Column(Float)
    buy_median = Column(Float)
    buy_volume = Column(Float)
    buy_numorders = Column(Integer)
    buy_fivepercent = Column(Float)
    sell_weighted_avg = Column(Float)
    sell_maxval = Column(Float)
    sell_minval = Column(Float)
    sell_stddev = Column(Float)
    sell_median = Column(Float)
    sell_volume = Column(Float)
    sell_numorders = Column(Integer)
    sell_fivepercent = Column(Float)
    
def __init__(self, title, release_date):
    self.typeid = typeid
    self.regionid = regionid
    self.date = date
    self.average = average
    self.highest = highest
    self.lowest = lowest
    self.order_count = order_count
    self.volume = volume
    self.buy_weighted_avg = buy_weighted_avg
    self.buy_maxval = buy_maxval
    self.buy_minval = buy_minval
    self.buy_stddev = buy_stddev
    self.buy_median = buy_median
    self.buy_volume = buy_volume
    self.buy_numorders = buy_numorders
    self.buy_fivepercent = buy_fivepercent
    self.sell_weighted_avg = sell_weighted_avg
    self.sell_maxval = sell_maxval
    self.sell_minval = sell_minval
    self.sell_stddev = sell_stddev
    self.sell_median = sell_median
    self.sell_volume = sell_volume
    self.sell_numorders = sell_numorders
    self.sell_fivepercent = sell_fivepercent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get it to work by using `bulk_insert_mappings()` so simply just by changing my `import_full_history()` to

```
def import_full_esi_history(history):
    get_data_session = Session()
    get_data_session.bulk_insert_mappings(Historical_data, history)
    get_data_session.commit()
    Session.remove()
    return 0
```

I got it to insert data. IT also works with multithreading and multiprocessing combined like I originally intended. Seems like `Session.insert()` only works with one column at a time and my dicts in the list was for entire rows